# How do I disable webmock for a Capybara tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm using webmock and VCR for some of my basic Rspec tests, but I want to disable webmock for my acceptance tests so that I can actually make external HTTP requests.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You might want to only use the `webmock` in some gem group and not in the `test` gem group

Answer (score 17):

you can just do

```
before do
  VCR.turn_off!
  WebMock.allow_net_connect!
end

after do
  VCR.turn_on!
  WebMock.disable_net_connect!
end
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [README](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#real-requests-to-network-can-be-allowed-or-disabled):

```
WebMock.allow_net_connect!
```